# How to force a portrait image to have the same size as landscape images and be responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive

How can you force a portrait image to have the same size as a landscape image and also be responsive?

I was trying to do this with the image [here](https://codepen.io/runaverse/full/dzqKLp) with the div class of bake-img and img class of back-img-2. I successfully did this, but it's not responsive. Any suggestions?

```
`<div class="col-md-6 ">
  <div class="bake-img">
    <img class="portfolio-img img-fluid bake-img-2" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/ottiya/image/upload/c_scale,w_985/v1504150918/brooke-lark-261287_rbw0mw.jpg" alt="yummy pastries">
  </div>
  <h4 class="portfolio-title">Bake920</h4><p class="portfolio-text">Alcatra kielbasa t-bone tongue, swine turducken boudin pancetta kevin leberkas. Bacon ipsum dolor amet brisket corned beef sirloin tongue ribeye venison. </p>
</div>`
```

Comment: You could start with creating empty divs with a border, and make them behave the way you want using CSS. When that works, you add your image as a background image for the div, and set it to `cover`. That way, all kinds of images (landscape or portrait) will perfectly fill out the div. Of course some borders may be cut off.

Comment: would you recommend that over using img classes and using css like this? .bake-img { 
  max-height: 273px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

.bake-img-2 {
  margin-top: -100px;
  
}

Comment: @kokodoko How do you know what to make the border size? I can't figure out what the dimensions of my landscape images are because since it's responsive, the size keeps changing :(

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have achieved what you wanted but without page being responsive.

[Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NvoaXq) what you mentioned is responsive because it have link to external CCS library called [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). If you google it you will find out that it is one of most popular and used framework library of CCS.

You can simply use this library by inserting following code to your head tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And following to your body tag

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I recomned you to watch some [introduction what bootsrap is](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=bootsrap).

Comment: Hi there! I am actually using Bootstrap. It is responsive, but not responsive in the way I want it to be